# Cannot use (type interface {}) as type int in assignment: need type assertion

Tags: go

I have a function with following definition:

```
type TreeNode struct {
    Val int
    Left *TreeNode
    Right *TreeNode
}

func BuildTree(input []interface{}) *TreeNode {
    // ...
    newNode := new(TreeNode)
    newNode.Val = input[0] // here caused the error
    // ...
}
```

I tried to do the type assertion:

```
if _, ok := input[0].(int); ok {
    tree.Val = input[0]
}
```

but still give me the same error

input is a slice like `[1,2,3,4]`  or `[1, nil, 2, 3, nil, 4]`, `nil` means that it is an empty node, I don't use  `input[]int` because maybe there are some nodes' value is `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) does not impact the object you are asserting on. Instead, it returns the value stored in the interface alongside a success bool.

This means that **you need to save this returned value and use it**. In your case, change your type assertion to the following:

```golang
if res, ok := input[0].(int); ok {
    tree.Val = res
}
```

Comment: It works, I started golang just few weeks, thanks for your answer so much